# Background SVG does not take up the entire view area when scrolling down

Tags: css, reactjs

I have made a react app and have an svg as the background. It all looks good unless. I make the browser really large or when i make it very narrow and then need to scroll down. When I do either fot hese two things the svg no longer shows and the lower part of the page has no background.

This is what I have:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  background-position-x: left;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  background-color: #ffffff;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg fill='%23d4d4d4' fill-opacity='0.50'%3E%3Cpath opacity='.5' d='M96 95h4v1h-4v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9zm-1 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm9-10v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm9-10v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm9-10v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M6 5V0H5v5H0v1h5v94h1V6h94V5H6z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

I have also tried using background cover and contain. But always I have the lower part of the page with no image/svg.
I have looked at other posts but the answers end up making my svg very zoomed in, as if it is stretching to cover the entire view area.

Comment: would you make a jsfiddle or something, it makes it much easier to give you the right answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.